# VS pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I use both Visual Studio Code and Anaconda. I'm trying to install Pillow to use in Visual Studio Code. I already have a separate Python environment outside Anaconda.

In the Windows command prompt, I entered:

```
C:\Users\Owner>pip install Pillow
```

Below is my warning:

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.'
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\owner\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (7.2.0)
```

How do I install Pillow correctly to run on Visual Studio Code?

Comment: You seems to have a python build that comes without SSL compiled in. That will create troubles with any kind of encrypted network connection. How did you install Python?

Comment: From the Python.org official website

Answer (score -1):

In cmd :

[image]

In VSCode, the steps to install and use the module "Pillow" are as follows:

1. Please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to enter the currently selected environment.
2. Check the installation tool "`pip`".

   [image]
3. Check the installation package.

   [image]
4. Run:

   [image]

Reference: [Environment in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).